# How do I modify REST response headers in a Spring ClientHttpRequestInterceptor?

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

Using Spring and RestTemplate I'm trying to call into an external service which does not return the correct content type as part of the HTTP response. Both JSON response and XML responses are returned with a Content-Type of text/html. I would like to use the same RestTemplate instance to handle these requests with an appropriate HttpMessageConverter handling the different response types. In order to do this I would like to implement ClientHttpRequestInterceptor, detect the content type modify the response header as shown:

```
@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest httpRequest, byte[] bytes,
                                    ClientHttpRequestExecution clientHttpRequestExecution) throws IOException {

    ClientHttpResponse response = clientHttpRequestExecution.execute(httpRequest, bytes);
    InputStream body = response.getBody();
    String bodyString;

    try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(body))) {
        bodyString = buffer.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }

    if (isJson(bodyString)) {
        response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    } else if (isXml(bodyString)) {
        response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected message type detected in response");
    }

    return response;
}
```

However, this results in the following exception:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://xxx.xxxx.xxxxxxx.xxx": stream is closed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: stream is closed
```

What would be the correct way to modify the response headers prior to hitting the RestTemplate message converters?

Comment: This issue is with reading the body InputStream as this closes the stream so the body can't be subsequently read.

Comment: Do you know how the JSONObject looks like? If yes, you can create a hybrid object containing the JSOnObject and receive. I don't know why you cannot simply do it with RestTemplates exchange by adding messageConvertors and getting the response.